# Confusion in Numerical Integration while using FindRoot

Tags: numerical-integration, equation-solving

I used this code for numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[(x^2 - .0015 x^4)/D[(x^2 - .0015 x^4), x], {x, 1.414, 13}]
```

when upperlimit of x is 13, the integral value is 50.

Now I want to find the upper-limit of this integration where integration value is known i.e. 50. I write the follwing code

```
PL = NIntegrate[(x^2 - .0015 x^4)/D[(x^2 - .0015 x^4), x], {x, 1.414, v}];
FindRoot[PL == 50, {v, 11}]
```

But this code is not giving me the correct value of v. Even when i change {v,11} to {v,10} or {v,7}, it shows different values of v. I plotted PL as a function of v from 0 to 14. But when I agian crosscheck using the ouput as upperlimit of numerical integration I do not get back 50.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You've been using the site for four months now.You should learn how to upvote/downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `Solve`

```
Solve[Integrate[
     (x^2 - .0015 x^4)/D[(x^2 - .0015 x^4), x],
     {x, 1.414, v}] == 50, v, Reals][[1]] // Quiet
```

> {v -> 12.9905}

Answer (score 3):

```
s[v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(x^2 - .0015 x^4)/D[(x^2 - .0015 x^4), x], {x, 1.414, v}]
FindRoot[s[v] == 50, {v, 11}]
(* {v -> 12.9905} *)
```

Comment: But when you change {v,11} to {v,1}, it gives different value

Comment: Is there any way to do this without defining a new function?